# Client server web API request

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have this code in vb:

```
If MsgBox("Current settings off. Employee weekly off's do not match the saved settings. Do you wish to update the current settings or keep the existing settings.", vbInformation + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2) = vbYes Then
   If m_WeeklyOffType = 0 Then
      .IsWeeklyOff = False
      .IsWeeklyOffHalfDay = False

   Else
      empTimesheetDeclareDetail.DateStatus = 2 
      empTimesheetDeclareDetail.MarkStatus = 3 

   End If
   mWeeklyOffSettingsSameForAll = True
   mWeeklyOffSettingsFlag = 1

Else
   mWeeklyOffSettingsSameForAll = True
   mWeeklyOffSettingsFlag = 0

End If
```

I am working on a web API controller and i am converting this to c#.
Everything was okay until i found a condition  where `MsgBox` is used in VB. How do i implement this in API? My controller is already executing, how do i stop(pause) the execution and request back to client with a msgbox and depending on his click (i.e yes or no) i further continue with his previous request?

Comment: How is the web endpoint invoked? Through ajax? Something else?

Comment: You can't. Message box confirmation must be done by javascript, then you pass the result as parameter (true/false) to the controller method.

Comment: @Max : But there's a condition, only if the condition seems to be true the message box pops up, i can't show the msgbox as the request is initiated by the client.

Comment: You will need to return a JSON payload to the web browser. The web browser will need to parse that JSON, and then, based on the payload, show a message box itself.

Comment: I see a `if` with `MsgBox`, replicable by javascript `result = window.confirm(message);` then call a controller method like `public IAsycnResult doMyJob(bool value) { if(value) {  If m_WeeklyOffType = 0 Then ..` where the bool value is the value of `result`

Comment: _"Do you wish to update with the current settings or keep the existing settings. [Yes] [No]"_ - uhm.

Answer (score 1):

To be very frank I think this is a business question not a technical. But the only way I see a work around is add an additional parameter in the request for this condition and based on that parameter you can decide what needs to be done here.

Comment: i already said, the msgbox is shown on a condition. I can't ask the client about the msgbox at the initial request. If certain conditions are true then only we ask about the message and depending on client's interest we further execute the previous request.